# Google Marker does not appear with user defined points

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

just wondering if anyone would be able to tell me how to solve an issue that I've been running into? The user puts in coordinates (ex: 85.231,40.213) into a text area, which populate and array, splits them, and then attempts to create a marker where the user specified.

```
var stringArray = document.getElementById("geos").value.split('\n');
var x = [];
var y = [];
var cords = [];
var array = stringArray.split(',');     //splits up array by ","
var j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)              //assigns broken up array into x and y values
{
    x[j] = array[i];
    i++;
    y[j] = array[i];
    j++;
}

var textarea = document.getElementById("test");
//textarea.value = stringArray.join("\n");  
//textarea.value = y;



for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)        //assigns x and y variables to coordinates
{
    cords[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(x[i],y[i]);
}

textarea.value = cords.join("\n");

for ( var i = 0; i < cords.length; i++ )        //code that plots all the points in the array
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       //create a new marker
    position: cords[i],
    map: map,
    })

    map.addOverlay( marker );
}
```

When I add ".toString()" in between "stringArray" and "split(",")" I'm able to output the items to another text area, however it seems that the information does not want to display. Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: What order are those coordinates in? 85 is pretty large for a latitude on a Google Map.  [This example of parsing coordinates from a text box](http://www.geocodezip.com/water_ca_gov_GeoRectifyA.html) may help you (the format is number, latitude, longitude), putting your coordinates in there (reversing them) gives me a marker in Xinjiang China.

Answer (score 1):

```
map: map,
```

that last comma will cause a syntax error, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do is make sure that your latlng coordinates are correctly converted from strings to numbers.  e.g. this might help, changing this line:

```
cords[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(x[i],y[i]);
```

to this:

```
cords[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(x[i]), parseFloat(y[i]));
```